Show Product Metafield on Collection Page or Home Page
I want to display a product metafield on a collection page or home page.
Here is an example:

And I want to display the metafield under the Product Price.
I've already tried it with product.metafields.custom.nameofmetafield.value but it isn't showing on the collection page.

Which theme is used on the website?

Local Theme from Krown Themes

First of all, you have to confirm that the metafield exists and is correctly assigned to the products you want to display it for. You can check this in the Shopify Admin under the Products section and see if the metafield is correctly set up with the appropriate namespace and key.
Second, the product liquid object is available on the product pages only. On collection or home pages, products are typically rendered using a loop of a collection or featured products, and you can access the product's metafields within this loop.
Here’s a typical example of how to display the metafield under the product price:
{% for product in collection.products %}
  <div class="product-card">
    <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
    
    {% if product.metafields.custom.nameofmetafield %}
      <p>{{ product.metaffields.custom.nameofmetafield.value }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}

If you already followed the above steps but still doesn't work, you'd need to provide some more context about your issue, and may share some parts of your code.
